# How can I raise a warning message in Odoo website

Tags: web, warnings, odoo

In Odoo 8, I am using a custom module which checks that VAT is unique, using @api.constrains('vat', 'parent_id', 'company_id'), and raising a warning when vat already exists.

But in the website purchase checkout form, I am making the customers enter the VAT. It happens that when a repeated VAT is entered I get a 500 internal server error, since the website does not provide a way to raise the warning.

How should I implement a warning, a pop-up or similar in order to avoid those internal server errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a JSON-RPC call to backend when submit button is clicked, before sending form data.

1. Create a new controller in python for validating a VAT:

   ```
   @http.route(['/vat/validator'], type='json', auth="public", website=True)
   def vat_validator(self, vat):
       # Your validation code here
       return 'OK'
   ```
2. Create a JS method for calling validator:

   ```
   (function() {
        'use strict';

       function vat_validator(vat) {
           openerp.jsonRpc('/vat/validator', 'call', {'vat': vat}).then(function(result) {
               // Your JS code here for checking backend validator result
           })        
       }
   })();
   ```
3. Set a form validation JS method like this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: Thanks Antonio. So I should write a different validator for website, instead of extending or modifying the current validator module, or just decorate my current validation with http.route?

Comment: You can use the current vat validator module, calling to res.partner.simple_vat_check method for example, or write another validator for your new controller.