# Catch error before process odoo9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

If enter wrong web code in my below example i get 500: Internal Server Error. Is it possible get validation error alert?

```py
@http.route('/web/process', type="http", auth="public", website=True)
def send_ticket(self, **kwargs):

    values = {}
    for field_name, field_value in kwargs.items():
        values[field_name] = field_value


    if values['web_code'] != "9999":
        raise ValidationError(_('Wrong web code!'))


    vals = {'name': values['web_name']}
    create_new = http.request.env['project.task'].create(vals)
```

Comment: Post the error you are getting, its stack trace.

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas Hi, when change raise validationError to print get this in console https://postimg.org/image/6cq22xy51/ here is error when stay raise validationError https://postimg.org/image/i471y55b1/  if web_code is wrong I need stop program and show error!

Comment: Edit your question and add the imports you have on your file

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas sorry but,I don't understend your asnswer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in odoo website module you can not raise error like we do in sale and purchase module.

to display error to user you need render same page with error label in your template .

this link many help you more [raise warring in odoo website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069000/how-can-i-raise-a-warning-message-in-odoo-website)